# Can we run selenium tests in GWT dev mode?

Tags: gwt, selenium

Can we run selenium tests in GWT dev mode?

Comment: I don't see why not. The DOM is still there. Have you actually tried? We haven't, really, because the Selenium tests ran in our integration suite, which just sparked up Jetty and deployed to it. More peace of mind that everything will work as a expected.

Comment: You should try first. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would only be possible using the out-of-process hosted mode of GWT:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/DesignOOPHM

Comment: There is only one Dev Mode in GWT.